# Perils and caveats of Kernel::eval in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, eval

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 p180.

I'm writing a continuous evaluation tool for [Rubyvis](http://rubyvis.rubyforge.org/) (to be part of [SciRuby](http://sciruby.com)). Basically, you set up the `Rubyvis::Panel` in your input file (e.g., `test.rb`), and this SciRuby class (Plotter) watches `test.rb` for modifications. When there's a change, SciRuby runs the script through `eval`.

The script works if I run it from the command line, but when executed through `eval`, the plot is wrong -- a straight line, as if all the data is gone, instead of [what you see here](http://rubyvis.rubyforge.org/examples/1_basic_line.html). *Note: Previously, it said here that the SVG was different -- but it turns out this was the result of REXML being loaded instead of nokogiri.*

[Here are the test scripts and eval code.](https://gist.github.com/1217929) Most produce the straight line (with exceptions described in the *edit* section below).

I haven't the faintest how this is happening.

I have a few ideas as to *why* it might be happening, but no clue as to the mechanism.

## Hypotheses:

1. `eval` doesn't allow deep copies to be made. Objects that are taken from `eval` are missing pieces in certain contexts, particularly when lambda is used to process the data into the correct format for the plot.
2. For some reason, `eval` is not honoring the bundled dep list when `require` is called --  maybe the wrong version of nokogiri is being used in my binding?
3. Some other required library (perhaps RSVG?) has overloaded some method Rubyvis uses.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I'm sort of feeling around in the dark -- at a total loss as to where to begin troubleshooting.

## Edit 9/15/11: new information

It seems that the call to `OpenStruct.new` is causing the problem.

If I define data as a list of lists, `data = pv.range(0,10,0.1).map { |d| [d,Math.sin(d)+2+rand()] }`, it works well.

But when data is defined as a list of OpenStructs, the following code gives incorrect output:

```
data = pv.range(0, 10, 0.1).map {|x|
  o = OpenStruct.new({:x=> x, :y=> Math.sin(x) + 2+rand()})
  STDERR.puts o.inspect # Output is correct.
  o
}
STDERR.puts "size of data: #{data.size}"
STDERR.puts "first x = #{data.first.x}" # Output is first x = 0.0
STDERR.puts "first y = #{data.first.y}" # Output is first y =     (WRONG)
```

I can even induce an error if I use collect when assigning the data, e.g.,

```
vis.add(pv.Line).data(data.collect { |d| [d.x,d.y] }

plotter.rb:88:in `block in <main>': undefined method `x' for [0.0, nil]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

versus no error with `vis.add(pv.Line).data(data)`. The error appears to originate from the call to `eval("vis.render()", bind)` in my app's source (not in the plot script).

It turns out that if I just use a hash, e.g., `{:x => x, :y => Math.sin(x)}`, that works fine. But when I explicitly say `Hash.new({:x => x, :y => Math.sin(x)})`, that gives an error regardless of how I call vis.data:

```
rubyvis/lib/rubyvis/internals.rb:184:in `each': comparison of Hash with Hash failed (ArgumentError)
```

So the difference is in how my data is assigned. The question is: **why?**

Copies of the inputs are available in the [original gist](https://gist.github.com/1217929). Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the output of `STDERR.puts data.first`

Comment: `#<OpenStruct x=0.0, y=2.8069015836625355>` or `{}` depending on whether I use an explicit OpenStruct or an explicit Hash. For implicit hash, it's `{:x=>0.0, :y=>2.8069015836625355}`.

Answer (score 1):

> It turns out that if I just use a hash, e.g., {:x => x, :y =>
>   Math.sin(x)}, that works fine. But when I explicitly say Hash.new({:x
>   => x, :y => Math.sin(x)}), that gives an error regardless of how I
>   call vis.data:

First of all, your call to Hash.new is wrong. Hash.new takes a parameter that's the default value of the hash.

Comment: My understanding was that Hash.new could take an object (e.g., another hash) or a block (giving the default value). My call is passing an object, not a block.

Comment: Okay, a second person repeated this to me today, so I'll take your word for it. But it still doesn't explain the OpenStruct problems.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this as a comment, not an answer;

Have you tried `load` instead of `eval`?